# Script to convert filenames to lowercase depending on extension

Tags: bash, filenames

Script to convert filenames to lowercase depending on extension

Answer (score 1):

To do it recursively for a number of extensions, you could use zsh's zmv:

```
zsh -c '
   autoload zmv
   ext=(jpg mp3 ogg)
   zmv -n "(**/)(*.(#i)(${(j:|:)ext}))" "\$1\${(L)2}"'
```

(remove `-n` (or replace it with `-v`) when happy).

Above the `(#i)` is to turn on case insensitive globbing, and `${(j:|:)ext}` is to join the elements of the `$ext` list with `|`. You could also directly write it:

```
zsh -c '
   autoload zmv
   zmv -n "(**/)(*.(#i)(ogg|jpg|mp3))" "\$1\${(L)2}"'
```

Comment: is zsh is more powerful than bash ? i see your code seems regex like syntax, but didn't understand , do you have any link for zsh noob ? i want to learn. thanks in advance . i will delete this comment after 6 hrs.

Comment: stephane i dnt know zsh could u pls help me in bash scripting....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your question links to the code, so I'll focus on the question.

In `bash` versions 4 and above, you can do this by using something like the following:

```
for file in ./*.JPG; do     # Iterate over all items in the current directory that match *.JPG
    mv "$file" "${file,,}"  # Move the file found to a lowercase mapping (this is what the ,, parameter expansion method does)
done
```

Obviously replace `*.JPG` with the equivalent extension you're wanting.

Comment: I am using 3.2.25(1)-release